# nginx configuration for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a wordpress installed in /var/www/blog. I want to access it through www.domain.com, so I created a domain.com Nginx configuration file containing:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    root /var/www/blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.domain.com.error.log;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But when I'm opening www.domain.com, the css/js files are not loaded. In my error.log I got:

```
2013/12/15 12:47:29 [error] 19562#0: *9 open() "/var/www/blog/blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: yy.yy.yy.yy, server: domain.com, request: "GET /blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css?ver=3.8 HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx", referrer: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/"
2013/12/15 12:47:29 [error] 19562#0: *11 open() "/var/www/blog/blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/navigation.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: yy.yy.yy.yy, server: domain.com, request: "GET /blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js/navigation.js?ver=1.0 HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx", referrer: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/"
```

I don't understand why "/blog/" is added in the links.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Here's my changes to your config, it's almost correct

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    root /var/www/blog;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.domain.com.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri; #change here
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # removed unnecessary lines.
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your config, but I got `2013/12/15 13:34:57 [error] 21982#0: *39 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php/blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css", client: yy.yy.yy.yy, server: domain.com, request: "GET /blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css?ver=3.8 HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xx.xx", referrer: "http://www.domain.com/"`. So I add a space between /index.php and $request_uri. And the css/js are now loaded successfully but the display of the wordpress is still unstyled, and when I click a link, the page is downloaded.

Comment: why is it trying to access the css through index.php ? shouldn't it be `/blog/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css` without `index.php`

Comment: Yes it should but I don't know why.